# File sharing platform for user contributions?

Tags: custom-post-types, uploads, media-library, file-manager

I am looking for a way to allow my visitors to share content between each other in an organized fashion. Essentially the ability to upload files or browse/download files that others have contributed.

These are just XML configuration files that contain a plethora of settings for a 3D printers, so at the core they are really nothing more than just text.

Before I go reinventing the wheel though, is there anything like this already available for Wordpress? If not, what would be my best option? I am thinking perhaps a custom post type, but giving anyone the ability to add them seems difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using BuddyPress groups with the BuddyPress Docs plugin (attachments enabled).

You need to allow XML uploads with:

```
add_filter('mime_types', 'custom_upload_xml');

function custom_upload_xml($mimes) {
    $mimes = array_merge($mimes, array('xml' => 'application/xml'));
    return $mimes;
}
```